# How do you select a stored procedure's return value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It seems like this would would be trivial, but my SQL is not up to par and I can't figure it out. I just want to select a returned scalar from a stored procedure. Basically like this:

```
select dbo.sProcedure @param
```

But that throws an error. It's not really an option to return a result set from within the procedure. Is it possible to do this, or do I need to start rewriting some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @SomeReturnValue INT
EXEC @SomeReturnValue = SomeProc
SELECT @SomeReturnValue
```

Comment: Note that while this works as a SQL query, if you're in a programming environment such as C#, there are better ways to get the return value.

Comment: Yeap. There are no C# tags on the question though!

Comment: That's interesting -- I actually am using C# for this, and this solution is working fine for me (creating a DbCommand with this text and calling executeScalar). But what's the better way?

Comment: @Ian: You would create a parameter and set the direction to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the sp an output parameter where you can store the required returned value, or use an scalar function

Answer (score 0):

@RichardOD has the right syntax, however as implied, you can't use it in a select statement. If you need to use it in a select statement, then use a function instead of a stored procedure.